# API REST para conversão de CSV em JSON

Tags: javascript, json, conversão-de-tipo

Bom dia pessoal, estou enfrentando um problema atualmente, preciso de uma API que possa converver CSV para JSON via REST.

Localizei varios conversores CSV para JSON na web, porém são construídas para uso no navegador e o retorno das conversões geralmente fica somente na aba de consolde do depurador dos navegadores.

Estou construindo uma aplicação que consulta em um servidor de arquivos um arquivo CSV, e o converte em JSON para que eu armazene tal JSON em um banco de dados MongoDb. Estou utilizando a plataforma APPERY.io para tal. 
Dicas de API´s REST para conversão de CSV->JSON ?

**Detalhe**, API´s para uso com node não me atendem pois a engine Javascript do node é o *V8* do google chrome, e a engine utilizada na plataforma APPERY.io é *Nashorn* que é incluída no Java 8.

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Há uma pergunta de processo similar no stack overflow - converting an csv file to a json object in java 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524191/converting-an-csv-file-to-a-json-object-in-java).

Comment: Obrigado @Rômulo Gabriel Rodrigues, mas a questão é um pouco mais complexa, pois a plataforma que estou utilizando é baseada no Nashorn, que é uma engine Javascript interna do Java 8, que difere muito da V8 que é a engine JavaScript do google chrome da qual o NODE se utiliza, a plataforma só aceita códigos javascript puro. Daí a minha dificuldade, pois caso fosse possível eu utilizaria uma API para o node, o que ajudaria muito pois é mais popularizada.  Mas desde já obrigado pela dica.